# Headphones are detected in Ubuntu only after booting once from Windows

Tags: audio, alsa, realtek

I am having a weird problem while using my headphones (3.5 mm jack). It is a dual boot Razer Blade 15” laptop having Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18 installed.

In Windows 10, I noticed that with the windows provided drivers for audio, the audio could not switch to the laptop's speakers after plugging out the headphones. The audio could switch to headphones automatically, but no audio from the laptop's speaker can listen after plugging out the headphones. To fix this issue, I reinstalled the audio driver and installed driver version 2.82 directly from [Realtek's official website](https://realtek-download.com/download-hd/). This way, audio can switch based on the device plugged into Windows 10. Please note that it is a completely updated OS, and no new updates are available in the windows update center.

Unfortunately, in Ubuntu 18, even after plugin the headphones, it does not recognize them. However, it recognizes in Ubuntu if I boot from Windows and restart to Ubuntu later.

I tried various solutions, such as [1](https://askubuntu.com/q/1118991) and [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/613613/) but no luck. My current workaround (booting everytime to Windows once and restart then login to Ubuntu) is irritating, though.

Comment: Try kernel 6.2.7 - if it doesn't work, file a bug report here: bugzilla.kernel.org You'll need to attach ALSA output when audio works AND when it doesn't work: http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thank you very much. The present kernel is 5.4.0-144-generic. I will install kernel 6.2.7 based on your suggestions. BTW, the link you provided says "404 - No such project"

Comment: `alsa-info.sh` must be available in your distro. Looks like the upstream is broken at the moment. This one works, in case it's not available: https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-utils/blob/master/alsa-info/alsa-info.sh

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov: Thank you for the information. I reported the bug [at bugzilla.kernel.org](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=217246). I checked it with 5.4.0, 5.6.17-050617, and 6.2.7-060207, kernels and found it.