# Computer using speaker even with headphones pluged in, Ubuntu 20.02

Tags: audio

When I connect my headphones, they don't just fail, they fail to be used entirely.

What I mean with that is that it uses computer speakers *even when headphones are plugged*, and no sound comes from the headphones themsleves.

I already checked this tread but no help: [Headphone jack not reliably detecting on Ubuntu 20.04](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/613613/headphone-jack-not-reliably-detecting-on-ubuntu-20-04?newreg=3fdc778006d842d6b246a25c5de49d29)

Comment: Have you checked the sound output? Only a few system automatically toggle. For all the other you need to manually select it. Please [edit] and update your question accordingly.